# Failed to authenticate account level SAS in Azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have been following the [latest writeup from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas) in an effort to generate an account level Shared Access Signature (SAS) for use with Azure storage services, notably Blobs.

Every time I perform a `PUT` request to my Blob service, I receive a `403` response, with the message:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

This is my function for generating signatures:

```php
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\StorageServiceSettings;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;

public function generateUploadLink($container, $folder, $filename)
{
    # get account settings
    $settings = StorageServiceSettings::createFromConnectionString(AZURE_BLOB);
    $accountName = $settings->getName();
    $accountKey = $settings->getKey();

    # define start and expire datetime stamps (ISO 8601)
    $startTime = (new DateTime('GMT'))->modify('-2 days')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $expireTime = (new DateTime('GMT'))->modify('+2 days')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');

    $parameters = [];
    $parameters[] = $accountName;       # account name
    $parameters[] = 'wac';              # permissions
    $parameters[] = 'b';                # service
    $parameters[] = 'sco';              # resource type
    $parameters[] = $startTime;         # start time
    $parameters[] = $expireTime;        # expire time
    $parameters[] = '';                 # accepted ip's
    $parameters[] = 'https,http';       # accepted protocol
    $parameters[] = '2018-03-28';       # latest microsoft api version

    # implode the parameters into a string
    $stringToSign = utf8_encode(implode("\n", $parameters));

    # decode the account key from base64
    $decodedAccountKey = base64_decode($accountKey);

    # create the signature with hmac sha256
    $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $stringToSign, $decodedAccountKey, true);

    # encode the signature as base64
    $sig = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

    # construct the sas (shared access signature)
    $sas = "sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=wac&se={$expireTime}&st={$startTime}&spr=https,http&sig={$sig}";

    # create client
    $blobClient = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService(AZURE_BLOB);

    # generate upload link
    $blobUrlWithSAS = sprintf('%s%s?%s', (string)$blobClient->getPsrPrimaryUri(), "{$container}/{$folder}/{$filename}", $sas);

    # return upload link
    return $blobUrlWithSAS;
}
```

A sample of my output, looks like this -- when making a `PUT` request to this URL, it fails with the aforementioned error message.

`https://batman.blob.core.windows.net/payroll-enroll/2019/test.txt?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=wac&se=2019-02-04T03:44:51Z&st=2019-01-31T03:44:51Z&spr=https,http&sig=ox7RdKGTKRYvGz2u9ScFv4TP4ZfduKxFhYdpvJKjE4A%3D`

By comparison, if I generate an account level shared access signature directly from the Azure portal, it looks like this -- when making a `PUT` request to this URL, it succeeds.

`https://batman.blob.core.windows.net/payroll-enroll/2019/test.txt?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=wac&se=2019-02-02T16:29:17Z&st=2019-02-02T08:29:17Z&spr=https,http&sig=omPc4ZwEdefDoHKqA4TqVOm3NUW%2BcKcNqTuD1hq94VU%3D`

I see no differences between the two, besides the start and expire times. As an aside, I'll also note that I have tried generating a service level SAS using the [azure-storage-php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php) package with the same result (*failed to authenticate the request*).

I have confirmed and or tried the following things:

- `$accountName` and `$accountKey` are returning the correct values, comparing to what is seen via the Azure portal
- tried each of `now`, `UTC`, and `GMT` as parameters to `DateTime()`
- provided ample padding (2 days) on either side just to make sure it's not a time difference issue as has been frequently noted in other issues I've read through on Stack
- applied wildcard (`*`) CORS settings to my storage account for `ALLOWED METHODS`, `ALLOWED ORIGINS`, `ALLOWED HEADERS` and `EXPOSED HEADERS`
- disabled `Secure transfer required` (allow both `http`, and `https`)

I am stumped.

**My Question**: What am I doing wrong while constructing the SAS, and why do I continue to receive request failures related to authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
$stringToSign = utf8_encode(implode("\n", $parameters));
```

to

```
$stringToSign = utf8_encode(implode("\n", $parameters) . "\n");
```

Essentially, you need to append an extra new line character.

Taken from the code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-common/src/Common/SharedAccessSignatureHelper.php.